# Why ldconfig doesn't link or cache my library?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, ubuntu-18.04

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, GCC 7.4

I created a test shared-library then copy it to /usr/local/lib/
The .so file has been created like this:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c src/Test.cpp -o obj/Test.o
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libhztest.so -o bin/libhztest.so obj/*.o
sudo cp bin/libhztest.so /usr/local/lib/hazeltest/
sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/hazeltest/
```

Then I created a test app and tried to run it and I get :
error while loading shared libraries: libhztest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If I do export a proper LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it works but I prefer to use ldconfig

Unfortunately ldconfig doesn't seem to link my library even though the directory /usr/local/lib/ is well included in the /etc/ld.so.conf

Anyone could tell me why this doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: In my case I'd incorrectly set the SONAME. Found it by looking through the output of `sudo ldconfig -v`.

Answer (score 3):

I finally get it running the command :

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib/hazeltest/
```

Comment: This only works temporarily. The ld.so.cache  is going to be overriden next time the system runs ldconfig (like when installing new packages.) See my answer for the proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy it into `/usr/local/lib/`, not `/usr/local/lib/hazeltest/`. Either that, or add `/usr/local/lib/hazeltest/` to `/etc/ld.so.conf`. (Although I think you're supposed to add this in a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` instead, like `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/hazeltest.conf`, so that you don't modify ld.so.conf directly which might be an auto-generated file).